# como trocar o valor de uma célula no dbgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando alterar uma celular `T` para `Sim` e `F` para `Não`, pois a visualização no `DBGrid` esta sendo `T` ou `F` conforme esta na Tabela no banco de dados.

Fiz muitas tentativas como:

```
procedure TFrm_Cadastro_Feriado.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
Var
  S: String;
begin
  if Column.FieldName = 'nome da coluna' then
  with DBGrid1.Canvas do
  begin
    S := Column.Field.AsString;
    begin
      if S = 'T' then
      begin
        S := 'Sim';
      end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usei dessa forma e deu certo.

```
procedure TFrm_Cadastro_Feriado.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
      const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
      State: TGridDrawState);
    Var
      S: String;
      aRect : TRect;
    begin
      aRect := Rect;
      if Column.FieldName = '**Nome da coluna**' then
        begin
        if Column.Field.AsString = 'T' then
        begin
          DBGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
          DrawText(DBGrid1.Canvas.Handle, PChar('Sim'), Length('Sim'), aRect,
          DT_SINGLELINE or DT_LEFT or DT_VCENTER);
        end
        else
        begin
          DBGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
          DrawText(DBGrid1.Canvas.Handle, PChar('Não'), Length('Não'), aRect,
          DT_SINGLELINE or DT_LEFT or DT_VCENTER);
        end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, o que você pode fazer é já no SQL que está ligado ao seu DBGrid, trazer o valor trocado das colunas, por exemplo:

```
SELECT case NOMECOLUNA when 'T' then 'Sim' when 'F' then 'Não' end as NOMECOLUNA FROM TABELA
```

Este é um exemplo usando Firebird 2.5, mas a lógica seria a mesma para outro banco.

Comment: Dessa forma não deu certo, pelo fato de alter o comportamento geral da tabela referente a essa coluna, quando faço o  case tenho que fazer a alias no final do comando com isso não reconhece na coluna por não existir no banco de dados